# Are there still sensors for a pen-type barcode scanner?

Tags: barcode

In 1980 there was HEDS-1000. in 2005 - HOA6480. In 2006 - HEDS-1300. Those were precision sensors with resolution as low as 0.13 mm at 4 mm distance. Now they are all discontinued and I cannot find a replacement. The only somewhat similar devices are "focused" (AKA "arrowhead") reflective sensors from TT electronics (like OPB702, OPB703, OPB740, etc). But they do not even mention any resolution or feature size in their specs and do not list barcode reading as a supported application. There are also reflective line reader sensors, like OPB739RWZ, but they require mush shorter operating distance (up to 1 mm).

Am I missing something? How do people these days make small feature scanners when full image sensor is not warranted?
Are there still some classes of sensors that I missed?

(I already have PWM to drive LED, Op-Amp and ADC to read sensor, stepper to drag the target, all I need is a sensor).

Comment: Oh man. I can't remember when it was the last time I actually saw one of those. When I was in elementary school maybe. I had forgotten such a thing even existed.

Comment: Since you can still buy these, yes, probably there are such chips available. Um, now comes the awkward part where telling you to ask for a recommendable part number or where to buy them (I'd know neither, sorry) is off-topic here...

Answer (score 2):

Since you can still buy these, yes, probably there are such chips available.

My best guess is that if you're in a pinch, you could make something like that yourself.

Since 1980's, LEDs have come a far way, and so have even the cheapest microcontrollers.

I'd personally just slap multiple cheap 0402 LEDs next to each other, say, two of them, and a photodiode in the middle:

```
      photo
LED 1 diode LED 3 
+---+ +---+ +---+ 
|   | |   | |   | 
:---: :---: :---: 
:   : :   : :   : 
:   : :   : :   : 
:---: :---: :---: 
|   | |   | |   | 
+---+ +---+ +---+ 

|<--  <2.0mm -->|
```

(top view)

Having two LEDs increases your sensitivity in forward direction even without lenses, but industrially, if you build a pen-style barcode scanner, you'd probably want your front lens to be part of of your enclosure design anyway, so you'd get a polyacrylat or similar plastic piece made to order.

Then, you'd have to realize that spatial resolution doesn't matter all that much – you can compensate for a lack of "tightness" of observed spot by doing better filtering of present and past measurements; after all, you know quite well what the relevant frequencies in your "dark/bright" patterns are, and with a modern microcontroller having an ADC with more than one bit, you get quite a nice sensitivity.

You can test that hypothesis yourself: Get a photo of your barcode of interest. Open it in e.g. GIMP, convert to grayscale, and apply a gaussian blur with a pixel radius (=variance) that corresponds to the radius of the core of the illuminated spot. Crop down your image to a single pixel height, full width of the barcode (and then some, if possible) and export it in a format that you can read with your favourite scripting language (Python, octave/matlab, ...). Apply a band-pass filter that reflects the expected frequency range (in 1/pixel) of your barcode (typically, 1/narrow bar to 1/wide bar, but depends on type of barcode). Play around with thresholds until you can see the edges of your bars again :)

I'd expect actual barcode sensors to feed the high-passed brightness signal into more or less a biased digital PLL running to allow to adapt to a human not being perfectly reproducible and uniform in speed.

Or, and of course: Get an optical mouse sensor. They do exactly what you want, namely detect how quick someone is moving across a surface, whilst some still offer an output for brightness. There were some datasheets for older optical mouse sensors that even described how to get something like "camera" screenshots (the sensor is really just a 9-pixel camera, often) out of it. Do that regularly, and you'll have something that is hard to beat in terms of accuracy.

Comment: My understanding is that focusing lens over the phototransistor is the most important. I was hoping to avoid designing my own lens and mount (the same true for a bigger image/camera sensor).
I already did some experiments with unfocused reflective sensor and results are so fuzzy, I doubt any filter would recover it.

Comment: Optical mouse sensor is an interesting idea, however: 1. still needs a separate lens. They used to be sold in kits (15 years ago): sensor, lens and assembly  (e.g https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Avago%20PDFs/ToolKitSelectionGuide.pdf), but now they are all obsolete. 2. Dealing with mouse sensor is almost as complex as with real modern camera, while I just have a single ADC input. 3. Much more expensive.